# actionscript socket readBytes() <- java app write() write() write()

Tags: java, sockets, actionscript, duplex

I,m a newbie in action script. I developing a flex application using socket for IO.

The problem is I cant read bytes through action script socket from a various writes from the server side without writing something to the server (that reads my writes) after each flexapp read.

For example this is works fine:

`server: write()`

`flex app: read()`

`server: write()`

`flex app: read()`

etc

But:
 `server: write()`

`server: write()`

`server: write()`

`flex app: read()`

leads to reading only first message

It seems like actionscript socket does not support full duplex mode. Is this true?

ps: First time I was thinking that it is a security problem, but now everything is done including
Security.allowDomain("*"); and policy file retrieval (Was also testing with crossdomain.xml file) - no  results;

psps: server side writes messages with '\n' at the end and flush() method is called each time after write.
The my code for a partial data retrieval is okay i think because it gets all the data sent, but only when doing writes after reads

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks, Andrey

Answer (score 0):

Full duplex mode has nothing to do it it, and every TCP is full duplex. TCP provides no guarantees about how much data is received at a time, and indeed you will find many threads here complaining that they *didn't* just receive what was written by the first write() in your example. You just have to read the byte stream and figure it out for yourself.

Comment: but my code waits for all parts of messages and is ready to read partial data. (in my example one read() means algorithm that ready to retrieve partial data) The problem is not all data can be fetched from the socket while server did 3 writes. Can only read first message, other in-algorthm read attempts return no data.

Comment: No data I mean - first message is read inside function called by SOCKET_DATA event. When algorithm worked (at the end of SOCKET_DATA handler function) socket.bytesAvailable equals 0. And no more events arrive... But if I place write() call at the end of handler function and add read() calls(like in first my example) into the server side code, events will come.

Comment: Sorry, found error in my code! All three messages was arriving at once, but I parsed only first of them by prepending size-bytes.